# Will using a `SPList` object derived from a disposed `.OpenWeb()` cause errors?

Tags: splist, spcontext

Will using a `SPList` object derived from a disposed `.OpenWeb()` cause errors?

```
SPList list = null;

using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("/myweb")){
    list = web.Lists["Awesome Name"];
}

SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will not be an error. I commonly use this design pattern to keep my `using` blocks small.

```
SPList list;

using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("myweb"))
{
    list = web.GetList("/myweb/Lists/Awesome Name");
}

SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
```

If you are updating an `SPListItem` in a manner that requires `SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` though, you will need to maintain the reference to the `SPWeb` (IE: do all the work in the `using` block.)

For more information about when you would need to set the `AllowUnsafeUpdates` property, see Hristo Pavlov's [What you need to know about AllowUnsafeUpdates](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/what-you-need-to-know-about-allowunsafeupdates/). It's the best explanation I've found about it.

I do this a lot so I don't have so many nested blocks in my code. It makes it a lot cleaner. Once you retrieve a list it's stored in memory. The same is true if you use the list only within your `using` block. If something gets changed between the time you load the list and the time you request a value (from an item for instance), the value you get is the value that was present when you loaded the list in the first place.

This is also why if you're only getting a couple lists you should use `SPWeb.GetList()` instead of `SPWeb.Lists[index]`. `SPWeb.Lists` loads all lists in the web on the first call. `GetList()` makes a database call each time, but if there are a lot of lists in the web you're loading a lot less into memory. It's a trade off.

Comment: But would this cause errors in the logs?